# Spring Authorization Server control Scopes

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I took a look at spring authorization server ([authorization-server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/0e509333bcf14fbee864330257f85a1c236f1d8c/samples/default-authorizationserver)  + messages-resource) and I'm wondering how to control the scopes a uses should have. Currently the scopes

```java
RegisteredClient
  .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
  .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
  .scope("message.read")
  .scope("message.write")
```

are hard coded for any user that authenticates he can get these scopes. But how would you control the users e.g. let user1 have `message.read` and user2 `message.read + message.write`? Is this out of the scope of what spring-athorization-server is meant for? Or should one customize the consent screen to show the checkboxes for the scopes depending on the user?